# Merge two pandas dataframe with mixed exact match by date and partially match by string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a use case to match room type of different hotels which is possible to have name variation for the comparable room types.  df1 represent the data of a given hotel (let say hotel X).  df2 represents data of its competitor (hotel A and hotel B).  The merging is described in the figure.  If I process row by row, it would not scalable processing.  The following code create df1 and df2.  Assume that all room type were written in lower cases and hotel X has only 2 competitors.  May I know how to efficiently process to get the output?

[image]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-26", "2022-06-26"],
                    "type": ["superior", "premier", "grand", "suite", "suite"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-15", "2022-06-26", "2022-06-26", "2022-06-26", "2022-06-26"],
                    "competitor": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
                    "type": ["superior studio", "superior double studio", "premier studio", "premier double room", "superior", "superior double", "grand suite", "superior studio", "premier studio", "grand suite", "superior"],
                    "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110]})
```

**UPDATE**
I think I found some solution partially by using pandasql as follows.

```
from pandasql import sqldf
df_A = df2[df2["competitor"] == "A"].reset_index(drop=True)
    df_B = df2[df2["competitor"] == "B"].reset_index(drop=True)
    
    sql = """SELECT
                df1.date,
                df1.type,
                df_A.type as A,
                df_A.value as val_A,
                df_B.type as B,
                df_B.value as val_B
            FROM df1
            LEFT JOIN df_A
            ON df_A.type LIKE df1.type || '%' AND df1.date = df_A.date
            LEFT JOIN df_B
            ON df_B.type LIKE df1.type || '%' AND df1.date = df_B.date"""
    
    temp = sqldf(sql, locals())
```

But I still cannot figure out how to do post-processing in pandas to get the expected output

Comment: Should `grand suite` match with `grand` or `suite`?

Comment: @CodeDifferent grand suite should be matched with grand (from left to right).

Answer (score 0):

I just write some code. The idea is basically using `explode` to expand the `type` column.

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date', 'type'], how='inner')
df2['type_split'] = df2['type'].str.split()
expand_df2 = df2.explode('type_split')
expand_df2['len_type'] = expand_df2['type'].str.len()
expand_df2.sort_values(by=['type_split', 'len_type'], inplace=True)
expand_df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'type_split'], keep='first', inplace=True)
df_merge_2 = pd.merge(df1, expand_df2[['date', 'type_split', 'value']], left_on=['date', 'type'], right_on=['date', 'type_split'], how='inner')
df_merge_2.drop(columns=['type_split'], inplace=True)
df_merge_2['competitor'] = np.nan
final_merge = pd.concat((df_merge, df_merge_2), axis=0)
final_merge = final_merge[~final_merge.index.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Comment: I think df_join in the line 10th was not defined earlier

Comment: I just fixed it, I forgot to rename the dataframe.